# How is phonology language specific?

Tags: phonology

I found this question in a phonology exam. I didn't understand the second part.

> How IS phonology language-specific?

> Give 3 criteria to show how sounds have different functions using examples from other languages.

Comment: The most important difference between phonetics and phonology is that phonetics applies to every human being, no matter what language they speak, while phonology only applies to one language at a time. Every language has its own phonology, but they all share the same vocal organs, and those are what phonetics is about.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The assertion is so broad that it is both true and false, depending. In this case the instructor tells you the statement is true, so you are to disregard the considerations showing that it is false, and therefore devise / recall the three main arguments that it is true. Unfortunately, if you weren't in class that day, you won't know what those three arguments are. If you weren't in the class at all and don't have the syllabus, you have little hope of guessing what the "correct" answer is. The wording of what exactly you are suppose to so – "how sounds have different functions" could, however, give you insight into how the instructor thinks, namely that you are to think in terms of sounds "functioning", which I suppose means "serving a purpose". Also, the term "sound" is vague, and that vagueness is probably important for the question.

As a preliminary, I would advise thinking of what "sound" is, and here I deliberately omit the indefinite article. There are three broad groupings of things that can be called "sound", namely physical events (e.g. compression waves), mental events (whatever goes on in the brain when you hear a car crashing), and linguistic things. Obviously in a phonology class the attention should be on the linguistic thing, and somewhat less obviously, there is some mental process that converts "mental .wav files" of perceived sound into single units. There are two views of what those units are – features, and segments. It is more likely that the instructor has in mind the segment view of those units, but still possible that they are thinking in terms of sets of features which combine to define segments. So let us say that there is a set of units like [a æ ɑ ɒ ɐ i ɪ y ɨ ɯ u ʊ...] which are "the segments". Now to a language-specific aspect of phonology. *The rules for converting continuous mental sound into discrete segmental units are language-specific*. The same physical event can be converted into [a] or [æ], [i] or [ɪ] or [e], in a manner that has nothing to do with the physical sounds, instead it is a conventional fact that a certain range of sounds in that language turns into [a].

"Sounds" as discrete linguistic units exist in at least two areas of the language faculty, the phonetic component and the phonological component. The phonetic component is responsible for turning more abstract phonological strings of sounds into some kind of physical manifestation, or taking a mental version of a physical manifestation and relating it to a sequence of phonological objects. The phonetic component does things like "makes the vowel a bit higher" in some context. Phonetics is the transition from continuous values of sound categories into entities that we call "language sounds", and it produces (interprets) those basic units of phonological grammar, the "contrasts" (or, phonemes – there is very little agreement among phonologists what the "contrasts" of a language are). To take a simple example, aspiration of voiceless stops exists in both English and Hindi, but the function of this difference between [t] and [tʰ] is very different in the languages. In Hindi, distinct words can be formed based solely on the selection of [t] vs. [tʰ] so we say that aspirates "contrast", but in English the choice is made by a rule that refers to the context where the segment appears. *Whether a pair of sounds lexically contrasts in a language, or is the result of a rule, is a language-specific fact*.

Finally, a given sound, one which is contrastive, may behave differently between languages, when you consider the system of phonological rules of the languages. Here we look at the question of "natural class" membership, which refers to the fact that rule often refer not just to single sounds, but to groups of sounds. Then the question arises, what are the sound-groupings that the rule system of a language uses. In Logoori, the consonant [h] "behaves like" a labial approximant. In Somali and various Semitic languages, [h] "behaves like" a guttural. In Shona, it behaves like a velar, in Spanish (some dialects) it behaves like an alveolar or dental. *The pattern of segment-groupings for rules is language specific*.